# LINQ Join query with Multiple Conditions in On Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to write a condition on equal clause in linq Query for the below sql query condition "and CO.ApprovalStatusID IN (2,4) "

Select   CI.CostItemId, CI.ParentId, CI.CBSPosition ,CO.ApprovalStatusID from i8control.CostItem CI
 left join i8control.ChangeOrderDetail CD on CI.CostItemId= CD.CostItemId
left join i8control.ChangeOrder Co on CD.ChangeOrderId= Co.ChangeOrderId AND  CO.ApprovalStatusID IN (2,4) 
where CI.ProjectID=3 and CI.isActive=1 --order by CO.ApprovalStatusId desc
group by CI.CostItemId ,CI.ParentId, CI.CBSPosition ,CO.ApprovalStatusID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your select, you might get rows where `CO.ApprovalStatusID` returns NULL, since you're using `LEFT JOIN` and you're not specifying any clauses for it in `WHERE` (which imho would be strange since you're using `LEFT`).

Your sample query states that your goal is not to get only `CostItems` where their `ChangeOrder` has `ApprovalStatusID` equals 2 or 4. Your query will get all active `CostItems` for project 3, and list their `CostItemId, ParentId, CBSPosition` and if they have a `ChangeOrder` with `ApprovalStatusID` equals 2 or 4, it will get that status (whether is 2 or 4).

It's kinda simple to generate that `IN` statement. You could create an `array of int` containing the status you want (2 and 4) and use it like this:

```
var validStatus = new int[] { 2, 4 };
ctx.ChangeOrders.Where(co => validStatus.Any(vs => vs == co.ApprovalStatusID));
```

Now, I can see two ways of resolving your full query, one using `LINQ GroupJoin` to perform the `LEFT JOIN`, another by using entity relationships. I used the last one assuming these classes as example:

```
public class CostItem
{
    public int CostItemId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int CBSPosition { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ChangeOrderDetail Detail { get; set; } // Idk if this is a collection or one single optional child....
}

public class ChangeOrderDetail
{
    public int CostItemId { get; set; }
    public int ChangeOrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual ChangeOrder ChangeOrder { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeOrder
{
    public int ChangeOrderId { get; set; }
    public int ApprovalStatusID { get; set; }
}

public class CostItemWithChangeOrderApprovalStatus
{
    public int CostItemId { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public int CBSPosition { get; set; }

    public int? ApprovalStatusID { get; set; }
}
```

Since you asked for `LINQ` and didn't mention any specific provider (which could be EF6, ADO.NET...), I'm providing which a LINQ statement (which would work for EF6, for example) that could be like this:

```
var validStatus = new int[] { 2, 4 };

this.CostItems
    .Where(ci => ci.ProjectID == 3 && ci.isActive)
    .Select(ci => new CostItemWithChangeOrderApprovalStatus
    {
        CostItemId = ci.CostItemId,
        ParentId = ci.ParentId,
        CBSPosition = ci.CBSPosition,
        ApprovalStatusID = validStatus.Contains(ci.Detail.ChangeOrder.ApprovalStatusID) ? (int?)ci.Detail.ChangeOrder.ApprovalStatusID : null
    });
```

Tell me if your classes are not like this, or if you need more details, or another way of executing this query.